# Unexpected result when adding computed column using case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server as shown below. I'm computing the percentage change from `value` and `prevvalue` column

```
CREATE TABLE temp 
(
   [date] varchar(7),   
   [name] varchar(1),    
   [value] int,
   [prevvalue] int
)

INSERT INTO temp ([date], [name], [value], [prevvalue])
VALUES
   ('2018-10', 'A', 10, 23),
   ('2018-09', 'B', 45, 23),
   ('2018-10', 'C', 55, 11),
   ('2018-10', 'D', 0, 23),
   ('2018-09', 'D', 22,  0)
```

This is my query. I use `CASE WHEN` to handle the divide by zero issue.

```
SELECT
    [date],
    [name], 
    [value],
    [prevvalue],
    CASE
       WHEN [prevvalue] = 0 
          THEN ([value] - [prevvalue]) / ([prevvalue] + 1)
          ELSE ([value] - [prevvalue]) / [prevvalue]
    END AS pctChangFromLast 
FROM
    temp
```

However, what I got as results is:

```
date    name    value   prevvalue   pctChangFromLast
-------------------------------------------------------
2018-10 A       10         23        0.00000000000000
2018-09 B       45         23        0.00000000000000
2018-10 C       55         11        4.00000000000000
2018-10 D       0          23        -1.00000000000000
2018-09 D       22         0         2200.00000000000000
```

The `pctChangFromLast` of rows 1, 2, 4 is not right. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `nullif()` to avoid divide-by-zero.  Then your problem is integer division.  In SQL Server, 3/2 = 1, not 1.5.

I solve this by multiplying by 1.0:

```
([value] - [prevvalue]) * 1.0 / nullif([prevvalue], 0) AS pctChangFromLast
```

This returns `NULL` rather than some outrageous number when the previous value is `0`.

Comment: I do need some large number when prevvalue is zero.   What did I do wrong in my code? Why I got those percentage number wrong? thanks  @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @zesla Need? I don't think so since you are completely misrepresenting the value. Does it make something else "easier" ? Perhaps. But let's be accurate and honest about the math here.

Comment: Yes, I do need in my work.   I need to capture those change. That's confirmed.   My question is what I did wrong in my code?

Comment: Let me clarify.  I need to track number of social media mentions percent change from last week to this week.  I need to rank them. I need to capture those not mentioned last week but current week. This is requested by our client. so need to do that.   @SMor

Comment: @zesla If that is what your client wants, then that is your requirement. Equally you should explain to your client that this is mathematical nonsense and get some sort of official statement that this is desired. Something like this often comes back to bite the developer (consultant?) who "should have known and said something".

Comment: @zesla . . . This question is about calculating the ratio correctly with integers.  I think this answers your question here.

Comment: I do get your point. But in addition to your answer, could you also point out what I did wrong with my code to get what I originally wanted.  I want to learn the column computation.   Then  I will accept your answer.  @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @zesla . . . The problem with your code is the integer division.  That is the second sentence in the answer.